# Do duplicates of "sin/cos/tan expect radians instead of degrees" needs to match the language?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

For example, currently [Why Sin(30) = -0.9880316240928618 in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36510910/why-sin30-0-9880316240928618-in-java), a Java question, in which the root cause of the question is about using degrees instead of radians in the sin() function, but now it is a duplicate of [How can I get sin, cos, and tan to use degrees instead of radians?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705123/how-can-i-get-sin-cos-and-tan-to-use-degrees-instead-of-radians), which is a JavaScript question.

Is it the normal way to handle "radians instead of degrees" questions like handling floating point questions ([Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken))? Or should we match the language when flagging these kind of questions?

Of course, it may have very low priority to reopen the question. The post is mainly asking the future actions to take when seeing similar sin/cos/tan questions.

A side note: I don't know if the following problems has been discussed before, but it seems the site has plenty of "sin/cos/tan expect radians instead of degrees" questions waiting to be closed as duplicates...

Comment: IMO using a question matching the language as a duplicate target might be better as there might be some builtin methods in the language to convert between degrees and radians, etc.

Comment: I find it frustrating to realize that this question wasn't settled, once and for all, as a general pattern, like at least a decade ago.

Comment: What we do for floating point errors in MATLAB is usually to leave two dupe targets, the general [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004) and the langauge-specific [Why is 24.0000 not equal to 24.0000 in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/686439). The language specific one tells you how to circumvent this thing within MATLAB, where the general target gives background on what the problem actually is, conceptually.

Comment: It's not really a programming problem though, it's math problem. All calculators have the same problem - you need to pick radians or degrees before using trig functions. Therefore this should come as no surprise to someone who knows the necessary prerequisites - which is basic trigonometry. It's not SO's role or purpose to teach kids math. This is a typical "OP lacks minimum knowledge of the topic being discussed", just close such questions. Questions asking how to best convert between radians and degrees in a certain programming language are fine though.

Comment: I fully agree with Lundin. These questions aren't really about programming. They may be about "why do people not read the documentation when they encounter unexpected behavior".

Comment: @Lundin Still easier - and definitely more helpful - to close the question as a duplicate than closing with the no longer existing "lacks minimum knowledge" reason.

Answer (score 24):

IMO:

1. For people who just ask why the code doesn't work, there should be one language-agnostic canonical, which *explains the concept* (it is *completely* possible for new programmers, especially younger ones, to have a valid reason to use trigonometric functions while not even being aware of the *concept* of radians) properly, explaining that the general approach is to convert degrees to radians explicitly by simple arithmetic, and perhaps make a wrapper. The canonical should be clear that this is the interface *most* languages provide, and give some justification (both in terms of the mathematical properties of radians, and in terms of the underlying hardware primitives / C library / whatever).

   - If the above cannot be identified, we *should not* repurpose an existing language-specific canonical for the purpose, but instead create a new one.
   - Despite that this canonical is language-agnostic, it should be willing to show simple examples in some language-specific syntaxes, just for recognizability. Languages can be roughly grouped into syntax families for this purpose. See for example [Why does non-equality check of one variable against many values always return true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337003) . For the question of applying a trig function, however, there probably aren't a lot of variants; it's going to look like `sin(theta)` (or possibly `math.sin(theta)`, or with some other namespacing operator) for pretty much any language anyone is likely to ask about nowadays.
2. For people who explicitly ask how to do it in their language, as long as there is plausibly anything to explain, there should be a language-specific canonical. If there is no special support in the language, a canonical can still be justified; it can have one answer, which says "there is no language-specific support; do the conversion manually".

   - Every such canonical should have a link somewhere to the language-agnostic one, and *should not* repeat the background theory more than a single sentence to introduce the link. Doing things this way naturally accommodates the possibility of languages where the corresponding functions use degrees by default.
3. This pattern should apply, mutatis mutandis, to other conceptual problems of the same sort.

Comment: I agree that a language-agnostic solution to explain the general principles would be useful, but it should (generally) be used in conjunction with a language-specific dupe target. One important case is the two arg form of arctan. Many languages / libraries expect the args in (y, x) order, but several important ones expect (x, y) order.

Comment: One rather confusing case is languages that provide rotation functions that expect args in degrees, but their standard trig functions work in radians.

Comment: I tried my hand at a canonical: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77585408/2805120

Comment: @PM2Ring I'm proposing a canonical for the degree vs radian issue. The interface for arctan is a whole separate issue. It's not as if a question needs to try to be a manual on trig functions. (That's what the Documentation project was for.)

Comment: Ah, ok. That sounds feasible.

Comment: I'm really sceptical about showing actual examples in the language-agnostic, general "why does this happen" Q&A. IMO the Q&A by @JustineKrejcha shows why this doesn't work well: it takes up massive volume to have even a few examples, people [just add their own](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77585409/8) for even more volume, and it forces a defensive choose-your-own-language-category-without-knowing-it-already writing style. FWIW, this largely also applies to the linked comparison-canonical with its arcane categorisation "where equality operators compare the actual string values" or not.

Answer (score 12):

Since the closure system allows having multiple links for duplicates, you could have *two* links.  One for the canonical assertion that trig functions take radians as input, and another showing how to fix it in your language of choice.  Of course I'd expect the canonical to include the simple advice to use `* pi / 180`, so maybe you wouldn't need a language specific link after all.  But I know at least one exists for Python: [How can I convert radians to degrees with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9875964/5987)

The hassle of having a second link of course is that it can only be added *after* the question is closed, and only by someone with sufficient privileges.

Comment: Although this is true, I rather dislike the idea that a large number of questions would be *repeatedly* closed with *the same pair* of duplicates. That makes one start to wonder why both such questions are there. When I see a multi-dupe, I tend to conclude either that the targets are unrelated (and this is an unsalvageable, too-broad question that was hammered to get it closed quickly) or else that there is doubt about which is actually the canonical. I would prefer that the question is closed with one link, that is chosen *according to how OP phrased the question*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Any language-specific canonical can and probably should link to the math-based Q&A about radians existing for details on that, e.g. "you need to `[convert to radians](link)` - then code in this language and any lang-specific explanation.  Or perhaps "You need to convert to radians; see \[another Q&A about the math\](link)."  That way we can dup-hammer to just lang-specific canonical and assume that anyone interested in learning (not just copying code) will see that link and follow it.  Lang-specific canonicals should probably avoid math-beginner stuff to avoid duplication.

Comment: @PeterCordes I agree. (Didn't I say that in my own answer?)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Oh, you did.  I read the first half then started skimming the rest of the page; I find I'm usually in agreement with your meta posts and editing work on main and I'd already decided I liked where that answer was going, so I skipped down to see if anyone had any different ideas.  But yeah, turns out we both thought of that detail, so it's probably a good idea.  But if a language-specific canonical isn't yet in good shape, making it a duplicate of both is very reasonable for people able to do that.

Comment: "...you wouldn't need a language specific link after all..." I want to emphasize this. If we start with questions of type: "how to do `*180/pi' in language X" we end up with a lot of low quality questions that potentially need curation. It's much better to link the general explanations of doing math in the respective languages instead.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution if you follow the link I gave as an example, you'll see that Python provides a way to do it without having to remember the formula.  No math.